# Idiom for doing trivial things during a crisis

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for an idiom for when someone will do small, irrelevant tasks during a crisis instead of working to solve the crisis.  The focus of the phrase wouldn't be on procrastinating, it would be about ignoring the crisis entirely.

Some examples:

- Choosing to organize the supply cupboard when a short deadline suddenly appears
- A stock trader doing low priority market research during a market crash
- Sweeping up the ashes while your house is still on fire
- Changing the oil of your car when you have 4 flat tires

Is there an idiom for this?  I feel like it has been on the tip of my tongue for days now.

Comment: [*Cats are notable (examples). Their self -licking is not solely hygienic; sometimes it is what psychologists call "**displacement activity**."*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22licking+is+not+solely+hygienic%22)

Comment: Only on EL&U can you find the answers to your burning language questions and learn fascinating cat facts simultaneously.

Comment: @John Clifford: I tried to find one that specifically mentioned the cat licking its *bum* (which I'm sure is my cat's way of saying *Pay attention to **you**? I'd rather lick my own asshole for the next half hour!*). But even though this is a well-known aspect of cat behaviour, I couldn't track down that exact one. :)

Comment: I think that's just such common behaviour that nobody felt it worthwhile writing an article on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one I hear most often is "fiddling while Rome burns."

Comment: That's the one.  I knew there was a musical connotation to it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common example of this where I am from is [to rearrange the deck chairs on the Titanic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rearrange_the_deck_chairs_on_the_Titanic).  It means exactly what you say in your title- to focus on a trivial or cosmetic matter instead of the real problem.

Another similar but maybe not as directly related expression is [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), which describes the tendency of some large bureaucratic organizations to spend too much time on the fine details of a project rather than the truly important features.

Comment: Two up and two down but no comments.  Anyone want to explain?

Answer (score -2):

Johann Wolfgang von **Goethe** wrote:

**"Things which matter most must never be at the mercy of things which matter least"**.

[image]